# While-loop for a PIN guessing game

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I created functions to help implement a 4-pin guessing game, with a while loop that tells me to keep guessing the sequence order until it matches the generated PIN.

```
import random

def genListDigits():  # No.1 Generates a list with 4 random digits between 0 and 9.
    myList = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        myList.append(x)
    return myList

b = genListDigits()

def convertToList():  # No.2 Receives my pin and converts it into a 4-digit list.
  convertedList = []
  for s in p:
    convertedList.append(int(s))
  return convertedList

p = input("Enter a 4-PIN code: ")
a = convertToList()
print('you entered', a)

def checkNumbers(guess,right):  # #No.3 Receives both lists, compares each element in order returns a string with 4 letters stating to go higher or lower
    result = ""
    for n in range(4): 
        if guess[n] == right[n]:
          result += "Y"
        elif guess[n] < right[n]:
            result += "H"
        elif guess[n] > right[n]:
            result += "L"
    return print(result)

checkNumbers(a,b)
```

However when I add while loop it doesn't seem to repeat the `convertToList` (`"Enter a 4-PIN code: "`) function. My while loop:

```
while a != b:
  q = input(convertToList())
print("Correct!")
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to put `p`, `a` inside the while-loop and check `a == b`, if true break the loop and print "Correct guess!"

```
while True:
    p = input("Enter a 4-PIN code: ")
    a = convertToList()
    print("you entered", a)
    checkNumbers(a, b)
    if a == b:
        print("Correct guess!")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly put your defs at the top. Otherwise it's hard to read. Your while loop needs to start before the assignment to p and end at check numbers.

Comment: This is not an answer you should comment